# Piranha CMS TinyMCE add class to image

Tags: tinymce-4, piranha-cms

I'm building a web app with Piranha CMS & I'm attempting to alter the TinyMCE editor to allow for adding a class to an image. I've seen the relevant TinyMCE configuration docs

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:image_class_list

However, even after updating the relevant tinymce.init

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/013ed850636a299c71f860f9ae769572e768af26/Core/Piranha/Areas/Manager/Views/Shared/Partial/TinyMCE.cshtml

to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/js/ext/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        mode: 'specific_textareas',
        editor_selector: "editor",
        convert_urls: false,
        plugins: [
            "autoresize autolink code hr paste piranhaimage link"
        ],
        image_class_list: [
            {title: 'None', value: ''},
            {title: 'img-left', value: 'img-left'},
            {title: 'img-border', value: 'img-border'},
            {title: 'img-responsive', value: 'img-responsive'}
        ],
        width: "100%",
        height: "340",
        autoresize_min_height: 340,
        @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/areas/manager/content/css/editor.css"))) {
        <text>content_css: "@Url.Content("~/areas/manager/content/css/editor.css")",</text>
        }
        toolbar: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist hr | formatselect removeformat | cut copy paste | link piranhaimage | code"
    });
</script>
```

I find there is no effect (I've definitely cleard browser cache). I've noticed that the plugin that TinyMCE in Piranha CMS is using is `piranhaimage` not plain `image` as in TinyMCE docs. If that's the cause, how to configure for `piranhaimage` then?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin code for `piranhaimage` can be found here:

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/master/Core/Piranha/Areas/Manager/Content/Js/Ext/tiny_mce/plugins/piranhaimage/plugin.min.js

Unfortunately the current version doesn't support overriding assets, just views in the manager interface, but it could be a nice feature to add support to the core plugin for alignment.

One way of trying it out in your local project is to download TinyMCE and place it in your local project, then copy the `piranhaimage` plugin to your local TinyMCE directory. After that you can change the following line in the TinyMCE.cshtml you've already overridden:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="~/res.ashx/areas/manager/content/js/ext/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js">  
</script>
```

And instead let it point to your local URL! Then you can change it to what ever you want!

Regards